# Excel Find & Mid functions for variable length strings

Tags: microsoft-excel

What function can I use to extract variable length strings, where all I know is the beginning and end points of the string.
So for example, I have a large list of domain names formatted like below, and I need to extract everything between the “://” and the “/” that occurs after the “.com”. One condition is that I also have some domain names in the same list that end in “.net” or “.ca” that need to be extracted similarly.

http://store.domain1.com/nn7/buyers.ncx?

http://www.domain2.net/nn6/buyers.ncx?

Comment: It's perhaps not terribly important, but this kind of bugs me: Shouldn't you have written:  >>that occurs ***BEFORE*** the “.com” <<
instead of >>that occurs ***AFTER*** the “.com”.<<  ? _______________________And isn't the generic term for ".com", ".net", ".ca", ".eu", ".org" ... et cetera,  et cetera "TOPLEVEL DOMAIN" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("//",A1)+2,FIND("/",A1,10)-FIND("//",A1)-2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. that worked great. now to learn how you did that...